# How to load xml from https using XmlTextReader

Tags: .net, xml, https, security

I am using `System.Xml.XmlTextReader` to read xml stream from a http location. Now I need support to read from a secure https site. How can I do this by providing user credentials in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation at MSDN for the [HttpWebRequest.Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.credentials.aspx) property. It contains a sample using the CredentialCache.

This may be what you need (in a integrated security scenario), but you might want to read the [docs of NetworkCredential](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential.aspx) as well if you want to provide a username and password as strings.

Once you have the HttpWebRequest working you just say:

```
XmlTextReader rd = new XmlTextReader(yourHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

Comment: Thank you. The NetworkCredential class was really what I needed to know to get this.

Answer (score 2):

Do you already have the relevant code to use `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest`? That would be my starting point - make sure you can download the data appropriately, then just pass the response stream into [`XmlReader.Create(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/756wd7zs.aspx).

You should be able to test the web part of things without parsing the XML - just print out the downloaded data to make sure it looks correct.

Comment: No, I have just used `Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(sUri)`. How do I implement `WebClient` or `HttpWebRequest` easiest to achieve what I want?

Comment: I don't have time to come up with full WebClient/WebRequest examples now, but there are plenty of them on the web, and I expect MSDN has some useful sample code too.