# C# Get xml site over SSL/TLS - https://

Tags: c#, xml, https, rss, ssl-certificate

I need to be able to read xml/rss from a https web site in a console program.

until now my program supports plain http, and i've been searching around but i cant seem to find an easy way to implement support for https.
It would not matter if the site has a valid certificate or not, but i would appriciate to get hints towards how i would check these certificates to.

I might not know too much about this so any hints are appriciated!

what i currently do for http is:

```
XmlTextReader rssReader;
XmlDocument rssDoc;
rssReader = new XmlTextReader(url);
rssDoc = new XmlDocument();
rssDoc.Load(rssReader);
```

When trying this on a site without a trusted certificate i get an error stating: 
"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."

```
string url = "https://somesite.com";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

My program needs to support both trusted and untrusted https sites.

Program is running on a server, and hence has to handle the untrusted https sites in code.

Comment: And what happens if you add "s" to "http" in the url?  Simply changing it from "http" to "https"?  If the site has a trusted certificate, it should just work.  If NOT, you'll need to troubleshoot any errors you get.

Comment: The site i am testing with does not have a trusted certificate. And my code needs to support both.....

Comment: which error are you getting  or what is the behavior? if you need to 'deal with certificate' error that's one/different issue

Comment: If the certificate isn't trusted, then the way around it is to explicitly trust that certificate on the machine that the console app runs on. To do that, open up the URL in Internet Explorer, install it from there.  There are instructions here: http://www.m86security.com/KB/KnowledgebaseArticle13446.aspx  (steps may look different depending on the version of I.E.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the certificate issue try the following...

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback((s, ce, ch, ssl) => true);
```

...somewhere at the start - or before doing the request.

That's basically validating any certificate unconditionally, a bit simplified.

EDIT: that's 'to blindly' trust (and is of global character for your app) - proper implementation would handle the parameters - or entails implementing [ICertificatePolicy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.icertificatepolicy.aspx) to specifically deal with different hosts/certificates.

EDIT (certificates): as to how the certificates and SSL actually work - and related to the above (based on the comments/discussion)...

http://www.verisign.com/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/index.html
[How does SSL really work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7381711/417747)
https://superuser.com/questions/84572/public-key-encryption

Comment: This can be just: `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, ce, ch, ssl) => true;`

Comment: @Porges :) of course - it's a matter of style, that's an old piece of code from before, when we used to specify the delegate etc.. But agree

Comment: Wow! It was just that simple! Thank you! :)

Would you mind explaining what this does? To me it looks like an event handler?

Comment: Yes simply it handles the certificate validation in a custom way - 'An application can set the ServerCertificateValidationCallback property to a method to use for custom validation by the client of the server certificate' from 'http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.servercertificatevalidationcallback.aspx'. Where there are problems it simply fails (and problem could be due to expired/invalid certificate etc.) and you need to handle that, something along those lines.

Comment: Sort of defeats at least part of the purpose of a certificate doesn't it?  The cert not only provides encryption (https) but it also helps to prevent main-in-the middle attacks, where the malicious website intercepts the requests and alters data.  Blindly trusting all certs takes away that portion of the cert's purpose, doesn't it?  Wouldn't it make more sense to specifically install and therefore trust thos one certificate?

Comment: defeats the entire purpose :) - sure - but this is a quick fix, and I'm not sure you can always trust the certificate properly. I often stumble on this and it's always for sites you know you're dealing with, API server etc.. And if the certificate expires or is invalid - you can't trust it really I think.

Comment: What would really be the difference between ignoring certificates that fails, or installing them, and then trusting it? Will this "quick fix" not use encryption then? I have always believed that when you run over https it always uses encryption? It would just not be validated from a "trusted" source?

Comment: I improved/added that to the answer. Certificate ensures that the site "you're talking to" is who it says it is - SSL both encrypts and verifies your communication - i.e. ensures that a) no-one (theoretically) can read it or b) protects you from others 'impersonating' - e.g. if someone intercepts your traffic and injects a false or malicious content, it can still be encrypted, if you trust it unconditionally.

Comment: And when running ServicePointManager.Server...... it encrypts, but it blindly trusts that it's the source i want to talk to, that i really talk to. or does the encryption not happen when running the command? (I am sorry for asking over and over again, i just want to be perfeclty clear) So the encryption key (certificate) would be not secure, but the connection is still encrypted, is what i am asking i guess....

Comment: I just updated the answer - it's not that simple matter, but better read from those expert on that - or maybe spawn another question with specifics, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to send an `HttpWebRequest` or use `HttpClient`.  Both of which are designed for making/negotiating these connection.

Possible Dupe: [How to load xml from https using XmlTextReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587806/how-to-load-xml-from-https-using-xmltextreader)

[How do I use WebRequest to access an SSL encrypted site using https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560804/how-do-i-use-webrequest-to-access-an-ssl-encrypted-site-using-https)

[HttpWebRequest with https in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542024/httpwebrequest-with-https-in-c-sharp)