# Can't load Telegram.org in C# webbrowser?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, telegram

I want to load telegram.org in my WindowsFormsApplication with `C#` in webBrowser with this code:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://web.telegram.org");
```

But result is empty.

How can I load this site?

Comment: I hope you are able to find some help in this [Thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10036161/c-sharp-get-xml-site-over-ssl-tls-https

Answer (score 2):

This is because dotnet WebBrowser control by default emulate IE version 9 but Telegram need IE version 11.
Change the default emulation version in Registry and it's work correct.
for change that value,you can use [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/793687/Configuring-the-emulation-mode-of-an-Internet-Expl)